# Reminding referee of reference invitation? Email etiquette

Tags: new-job, applications, email, references

I am applying for a very important MSc position which requires a reference.

Through an email conversation, my old professor said,

> Should you require a reference please do not hesitate to ask

I followed him up thanking him and saying yes. It will be very appreciated for the upcoming application.

However due to getting an interim transcript sorted out, I have not been able to finalise the application until now, almost 3 weeks later.

Should I go ahead and submit the application as he is already aware? Remind him I'm about to submit and wait for his response? Or tell him after I've submitted?

I understand professors are very busy, so the last thing I would want to do is pester him.

Comment: I thought that was clear @JoeStrazzere? *I followed him up thanking him and saying yes. It will be very appreciated for the upcoming application.* To me, the OP has asked the professor to be a reference for the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already told him that you would be using him as a reference from the previous communication. Sometimes companies take time in contacting references, so I wouldn't worry about your delay in sending the application.

Send your application now, if you want to, you can also send the professor a little reminder about that you have asked him to be a reference and that he may get contacted in the next few weeks, however it is not mandatory.

As long as the delay hasn't been more than 6 months, from asking the professor to be a reference to sending the application, I wouldn't worry about it. In the real world, job applications take time. If I was asked to be a reference, I wouldn't expect a call from a company within the next week.